# What is the price of Crunchyroll membership as of 2019?

Tags: crunchyroll

I'm not sure if people have heard yet but Crunchyroll is raising their prices in 2019.

When will this take effect, and if so how much will the subscription be per month after they raise the prices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To continue growing our simulcast and catalog offering, the price of the **One-Month Premium** membership will increase to **$7.99 USD** for new users on May 1, 2019.
>
> However, as an existing Premium member, we're pleased to report that your current subscription rate is locked in at $6.95 USD for three months. After August 1, 2019, your following billing cycle will be charged at $7.99 USD.

The text above is directly from an email sent to current premium members, but the information can be found on a large number of sites, including [Variety](https://variety.com/2019/digital/news/crunchyroll-price-increase-1203170353/).

Comment: OK thank you I don't check emails from them too much I might have gotten it but I didn't notice.